# Selecting value from a JSON string

Tags: c#, json

I am having a heck of a time getting a particular value from json and am hoping someone can help. The json I'm using comes from a form post, so will typically be different each time, but the IDs will always be the same (just like every form!)...and I do not have control over the format of the json. I am able to get the name value from this just fine (using Newtonsoft.Json), but am stuck on how to get the "More then 5 years" value...

Here is what I am using to get the "My name is" value, which (obviously) doesn't work for "Years of Employment".

**C#:**

```
obj["form_response"]["answers"].SelectToken("$.[?(@field.id == '26')]..text").ToString();
```

**JSON:**

```
{
   "event_type":"form_response",
   "form_response":{
      "definition":{
         "id":"c33500e5",
         "title":"Employee Satisfaction",
         "fields":[
            {
               "id":"33",
               "title":"Years of employment:",
               "type":"multiple_choice"
            },
            {
               "id":"26",
               "title":"My name is:",
               "type":"short_text"
            }
         ]
      },
      "answers":[
         {
            "type":"choice",
            "choice":{
               "label":"More than 5 years"
            },
            "field":{
               "id":"33",
               "type":"multiple_choice"
            }
         },
         {
            "type":"text",
            "text":"Bill Dunn",
            "field":{
               "id":"26",
               "type":"short_text"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do not you just create a class and deserialize on it? http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: Your JSON is invalid at line 32.  Post it to https://jsonlint.com/ to see the error.  Can you [edit] your question and include valid JSON?

Comment: You mean you want this?  `var result = obj["form_response"]["answers"].SelectToken("$.[?(@field.id == '33')].choice.label");`  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i3st46).  Or is it that field 33 is polymorphic and will sometimes have different formats?

Comment: Thanks everyone, dbc that worked. So simple, I thought I had to use '@label'...

Comment: ...and thanks for fixing the json structure. I had tried to remove the other questions as they were all 'short_text' and the one 'multiple_choice' that I was having a problem with. Thanks again, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you want is nested as follows: `{ "choice": { "label": "More than 5 years", ... } }` so you can do:

```
var result = obj["form_response"]["answers"].SelectToken("$.[?(@field.id == '33')].choice.label");
var resultJson = result.ToString();
```

Comment: Yep, that did it. Thanks again!

Comment: ps, I tried to up-vote you, but I guess I'm too much of a noob for it to register.